# Commit option faded in Xcode,Unable to select the option

Tags: ios, xcode

I had checked the repository account and it is fine but unable to commit the changes in my project ,commit button just faded off unable to select because of that.
[image: click here for screen shot]

Comment: Can you show me screen short ?

Comment: i just edited ,u can see screenshot now

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to a version repository...

Comment: according to your image you looks like you don't have anything to commit if you are connected to repository and if modify something Xcode will show indication on right side of the file name

Comment: You have not made a single change in your code. Modify something `M` will appear in front of that file and then `commit` will be enabled.

Comment: I done lot of changes but it's not showing

Answer (score 0):

Check for remote url added to your Xcode project. The fade is actually due to reason your project is not connected to your repo.